# GenGetOpt - Allow only "--option" and not "-option"

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I am having troubles to define an option to only accept "--" and not "-" version.

for example:

> option "test" - "a test option" string typestr="[value]" optional
>   multiple

When running my program, it is allowed to run both:

> run -test asd

and

> run --test asd

I wish -test to not be allowed and fail the software.
I read the gengetopt manuals but didn't seem to find anything related to that.

Thanks!

Comment: For C++ we have better choices, e.g. Boost Program Options. That's native C++, without need for an extra build tool.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the way the software works

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution might be to just check `argv[]` yourself before passing it over to the generated `cmdline_parser()`.

Comment: A primitive solution, but it might work! Thanks :) Voted +